# how to add picture to a SharePoint list?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. I want to add a list with two columns, one column displays picture, and the other column displayes rich text. I did not find a way to display picture itself into a list (picture type column of list seems only add a link of picture to the column, not the picture itself). Any ideas how to implement? And is it possible to implement paging on list -- e.g. display 20 items on each page, and if 100 items, display by 5 pages (end user could use page-up and page-down to control paged view)?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a picture library, and then add that webpart to your page.  It's already setup to show a thumbnail of the picture in the list, and you could customize the view to show a description column as well.  When modifying the view, you can also display how many items are shown per page.

Comment: "that webpart to your page" -- what web part do you mean?

Comment: Cool, Sean! Question answered!

Comment: I assume you figured it out, but you would edit the page (Site Actions --> Edit Page), click "Add a Web Part", and then select the picture library that you just created.